# Certain HTML doesn't want to get shown/hidden in IE. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="loading-overlay">
    <div id="loading-overlay-background"></div>
    <div id="loading-overlay-content">
        Processing...
        <br />
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/ajax-loader.gif")" title="" alt="Please Wait" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#loading-overlay
{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:5000;
}
#loading-overlay-background
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index:5001;
}
#loading-overlay-content
{
    position:fixed;
    top:25%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    height:40px;
    width:300px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:15002;
}
```

And here is some JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'controller/action',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#loading-overlay').show();
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#loading-overlay').hide();
                }
            });
```

Why isn't my "loading overlay" showing up in any version of IE on any AJAX call?

EDIT:  Yes, it works great in FireFox and Chrome.  These AJAX calls could take anywhere from a fraction of a second to about 20 seconds to complete.  Alert messages do show up, but the HTML doesn't.

Comment: How quickly are the AJAX calls taking to complete? If they're fast enough, the `#loading-overlay` element will show then hide again and may not be noticeable.

Comment: it works in the other browsers?

Comment: I would say the ajax is completing to quickly. Put an alert after the `show()` call to see if it shows

Comment: I think you ajax gets executed to fast ! try to do an alert() before you call .hide() maybe this would work. or you could simply delete the .hide() and then see if it gets displayed

Comment: Check out [http://jsfiddle.net/yzZSU/](http://jsfiddle.net/yzZSU/).  In IE 9 and compatibility both works.  We would need access to your page to fully test this i guess.

Comment: Have you tried putting an alert in beforeSend to make sure it's getting called? If you use a JS console and call the .show() and .hide(), does it work then? Maybe the element shows up but doesn't like the 100% w/h?

Comment: Using console in IE9 (developer's tools).  It's showing/hiding perfectly.  I cannot give anyone access to this page.

Comment: @Henesnarfel - It works by itself, I know that.  It's something about this combination of HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
beforeSend: function () {
   $('#loading-overlay').show(1);
},

complete: function () {
    $('#loading-overlay').delay(500).hide(250);
}
```

See it in action, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j2TLJ/)..

**EDIT:**

You may also try decreasing the animation frame rate.

Using `jQuery.fx.interval = 50;`

By default, this is set to 13 ms. Increasing this could reduce the burden on CPU resources with the use of `.fadeIn()`. But caution is advised while tweaking this. Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/).

Comment: Looks like it's coming up, but I need to get to the office to see it clearly in action.  Going to the office now.

Comment: Ok.  It's coming up, but it looks to me like the .show() in beforeSend fires up when it already executes JS inside of success.

Comment: I did some work based on this answer. In short, I rewrote some code inside of success to speed up the processing time and changed .hide() to .fadeIn(200).  There is something about animation vs. plain CSS change (.show()) that IE is handling differently. It's still not ideal, but the business excepted.  Moving on for now, might get back to this problem some time in the future. Thanks!

Comment: My bad! I actually used .fadeOut().  Also, I received a complaint about IE not rendering the animation correctly.  Changing it to .fadeOut(1) seemed to "fix" the IE issue.

Comment: @Dimskiy: Using `fadeOut(1)` i.e. fade over 1 millisecond has no animation benefits. You might as well use `.css('display', 'none')`, It would be much faster and less bug prone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys , I was just very confused as my overlay was shown in all the browsers except for IE , now this works very well for all the browsers, I have integrated the same in a jsf page and it is good.

Answer (score -2):

Because you hide it in complete.

It gets called after success/error callback.

Comment: its supposed to show before send the ajax then it is hidden after the ajax finishes